# NetBeans Platform Lookup and CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, lookup, netbeans-platform

I have 3 classes in the same Module:

1. MenuAPI (Interface)
2. MenuJPanel (JPanel)
3. Demo (JPanel)

I am trying to switch between the Panels, using CardLayout, on the MenuJPanel using the NetBeans Platform Lookup. For some reason only the System.out text gets printed but cards are not shown/switched. The following is just a short code example (I created and defined the CardLayout properly in my original code.):

```
    public interface MenuAPI {

        public void showPanel1();

        public void showPanel2();
    }

    @ServiceProvider(service = MenuAPI.class)
    public class MenuJPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel implements MenuAPI {

        private void displayPanel(String s) {
            CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) this.getLayout();
            cardLayout.show(this, s);
        }

        @Override
        public void showPanel1() {
            System.out.println("Panel1");
            displayPanel("panel1");
        }

        @Override
        public void showPanel2() {
            System.out.println("Panel2");
            displayPanel("panel2");
        }
    }

    public class Demo extends javax.swing.JPanel{

//This is just a button with an Event Listener
        private void btnShowPanel1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            MenuAPI menuAPI = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(MenuAPI.class);
            menuAPI.showPanel1();
        }
}
```

Comment: +1 for endless bothering with to override GUI Framework :-)

Comment: hehe thanks :). I know I am annoying, but can you please move me in the right direction. Thank you mKorbel

Comment: Please show the code where you add MenuJPanel to a container (JFrame or TopComponent). Make sure you obtain the MenuJPanel in this code via Lookup and don't create it yourself. Otherwise you will end up with two instances of MenuJPanel. One is attached to your Frame and the other is sending you the lovely greetings via System.out while being invisible.